# ngPdf - zoomOut and zoomIn - center

Tags: css, angularjs, canvas, zooming

I use pdf canvas to preview PDFs in my AngularJS/Bootstrap application.
This preview works really excellent.
The only thing I would need is to center either my modal or the canvas when
zoom in with:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="zoomIn()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
</button>
```

These are my div containers:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="pdf-canvas" class="rotate0"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="pdfTemplateModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove close" data-ng-click="vm.closePdfTemplateModal()"></span>
    <div class="pdfPreviewWrapper">
        <ng-pdf template-url="app/project/templates/pdfTemplate.html" canvasid="pdf-canvas" page="1" scale=1 debug="true" ></ng-pdf>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a possibility to center the canvas when zooming in?
Currently the canvas is fixed at top left of my AngularJS/Bootstrap modal but it should be centered when zooming in.

Comment: Do you try using a simple css rule for its container?

Comment: Can you setup a working demo?

Comment: This is the demo of the project and I use it in the same way: https://sayan.ee/angularjs-pdf/ - Thanks a lot for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. Delete for .wrapper "width"

2. For ng-pdf add

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

3. For NAV add
    width: 1000px;

4. For H1 add 
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
```

Look my result to this link - https://www.screenmailer.com/v/ikcGUb7B91yaNlA

Comment: hmm, I still have problems with this issue. Would it be possible to provide your complete css concerning this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3318489 I do this in browser inspector. Show me your result